# Triggering event on openlayers feature

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers, layer, eventtrigger

I have a web map with vector points. Once you click one, FramedCloud popup appears with data based on this feature.vector attributes. 
There is an option to search through all points by input text field with added jquery autocomplete. However, if user uses this autocomplete, only one vector.point remains on the whole map. I would like to make that this point is automatically clicked.

```
 selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(warstwa_ikon, { onSelect: PopupLokal, onUnselect: destroyPopup }
```

warstwa_ikon is my vector layer, PopupLokal(feature) is function generating FramedCloud.

I tried this:

```
map.events.triggerEvent('click', warstwa_ikon.features[0]);
```

But it gives an error: **TypeError: (intermediate value)._featureId is undefined**.
I was trying warstwa_ikon.features[0].id and few other methods of giving this function id of my lonely vector point, but with no success.

Comment: To clarify: i have only one vector point, and I want to trigger click event on it. Im using OpenLayers version 2.